# Is peer-reviewing lighter in ACM-SIAM proceedings?

Tags: mathematics, peer-review, journals, errors-erratum, proceedings

I am having problems understanding some inequalities proved in a paper from the [2019](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611975482) Proceedings of SODA (annual symposium organized by ACM and SIAM). These proceedings are very helpful and I do not want this question to be viewed as a critic to SIAM, ACM or that Symposium that I pretty much appreciate. I just want to understand if the peer-review process followed in these proceedings is comparable to the peer-review process in a classical research journal.

I have been dealing with these inequalities during some weeks now but I cannot understand them or how they are obtained because the explanation for their derivation is poorly (or not even) written in the paper. Now the paper comes from very respected authors in the field and thus I believe that the most probable thing is that I am unable to understand their correct argument. Of course, the highest probability is for the fault to be on me.

However, I really suspect that the derivation of these inequalities could not be well explained in the paper. I suppose they are right but they are used in the proof of the main theorem and the impossibility to follow them is driving me crazy as I really need to compute some estimations based on the arguments provided there.

This is why I want to know if it might be possible that the argument (not the result itself) might be wrong because maybe the peer-review in these proceedings is lighter than in a journal. In the site of the proceedings, it is written that they are peer-reviewed. But I do not know if it was like this all the times or if that changed recently. I do not mention the paper that it is driving me crazy (and making me lose a lot of time) itself in order not to put some (maybe) unjustified doubts on authors that I deeply respect.

Please, delete this question if you think that it is inappropriate. I really do not want to harm anybody with this question.

Comment: May I ask why the downvote? I would like to know how to improve the question if someone believe it can be done.

Comment: It sounds like you're under the impression that peer review removes all errors, therefore if you encounter errors / difficulties in understanding the paper then the peer review must have been lighter. If so, remember that peer review is highly random, and you could be seeing an outlier.

Answer (score 2):

Reviewers for proceedings in general have much less time than reviewers for journals. This is because conferences offer a certain decision date (which in practice can be postponed by a few days), but journals at best only advertise average time-to-decision.

Also, for conference proceedings the number of rounds is limited and often only one. This means that authors can react to the comments of the reviewers only in their final version. Sometimes, there is "shepherding" (at least in some prestigious CS conferences), where the final approval of the paper is left to the shepherd, so that authors get a second look by an outsider on their paper.

I have no idea how SODA works, so these remarks only apply to CS conferences in general. A journal refereeing process by its
nature can be more intensive than that for a conference. The more mathematical the paper, the more difficult since Mathematics has a tradition of explaining only the non-obvious with the result of smaller, denser papers but the disadvantage of a bigger chance for an error to slip by. As a reviewer, I know how easy it is to forget to check details if the paper is written well. If there is time pressure, it takes dedication and excellent time management to read each paper as carefully as it should be. If a referee is not doing the job, an "emergency" reviewer might have only a couple of days.

Another difficulty of the conference system is the inability for Errata.

In your case, you should try to contact the authors about your doubts. In general, authors like it when their paper is read.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your remarks!